# Run php script with cron mac - every 10 seconds

Tags: macos, cron

I am trying to run in mac a php script using cron. I want this php script to run every 10 second. I read several sources online and from my understanding is better if I use launchd. In any case, I try to make it work with cron and then if it works fine I might try to use launchd.

So here is what I do but its run every one minute:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://localhost:8888/atms_final/data/demos/editing/loop_tasks.php
```

How I can change it to run every 10 seconds

Comment: Cron only allows for a minimum of one minute. What you could do is write a shell script with an infinite loop that runs your task, and then sleeps for 10 seconds. That way your task would be run more or less every 10 seconds, depending on how long the task itself takes.

Answer (score 0):

`cron` is a bit too coarse-grained for a 10 second repetition rate.

Consider making a little script like this and saving it as `curler`

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do
   echo curling...
   /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://localhost:8888/atms_final/data/demos/editing/loop_tasks.php
   sleep 10
done
```

Then, in the Terminal, you can make it executable (just do this once):

```
chmod +x curler
```

Then you can run this in the Terminal:

```
./curler
```

Or you can run `curler` **once** from `cron`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this -

```
*/1 * * * * curl --silent --compressed http://localhost:8888

*/1 * * * * sleep 10; curl --silent --compressed http://localhost:8888

*/1 * * * * sleep 20; curl --silent --compressed http://localhost:8888

*/1 * * * * sleep 30; curl --silent --compressed http://localhost:8888

*/1 * * * * sleep 40; curl --silent --compressed http://localhost:8888

*/1 * * * * sleep 50; curl --silent --compressed http://localhost:8888
```

**Explanation -**

So technically you have 6 cron jobs all running each minute, but each job has a trailing sleep time, which make the run all at a difference of 10 seconds.